# "Unknown option "PATH=[...]"" when following the official ffmpeg compilation guide

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, compile, make

I wanted to compile ffmpeg myself in order to get a smaller executable I can then dristribute with my program.
While following the official [ffmpeg compilation guide for Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) I get an error when it comes to actually compiling ffmpeg as described in section *Compilation & Installation -> FFmpeg*.
The following long compound command is given.

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
cd ffmpeg && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --ld="g++" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-gnutls \
  --enable-libaom \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libsvtav1 \
  --enable-libdav1d \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-nonfree && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install && \
hash -r
```

I only want to include the libvpx encoder and not install ffmpeg, only compile it. That leaves me with this slightly shorter command.

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
cd ffmpeg && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --ld="g++" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-libvpx \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
hash -r
```

This compound command consists of 6 individual commands. When executing the longest, 5th command

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --ld="g++" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-libvpx \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make
```

I get this error

```
Unknown option "PATH=/home/joker/bin:/home/joker/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin".
See ./configure --help for available options.
```

where joker is my username on this virtual machine.

I am using Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla x64 with all the latest updates.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside, your final command includes all native components. You probably could disable filters, encoders, muxers that you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts:

- `\` before a newline character tells the shell the command continues in the next line.
- `foo=bar baz` runs `baz` with `foo` variable in the environment.
- `baz && qux` runs `qux` iff `baz` returns success (exit status `0`).

The original command was like

```sh
… && \
PATH=… PKG_CONFIG_PATH=… ./configure \
  … \
  --enable-nonfree && \
PATH=… make && \
…
```

Equivalently

```
… && PATH=… PKG_CONFIG_PATH=… ./configure … --enable-nonfree && PATH=… make && …
```

So the structure was like

```
… && ./configure … && PATH=… make && …
```

You turned it into something that is like

```
… && ./configure … PATH=… make && …
```

and `PATH=…` is now an option to `./configure`. This is wrong.

In other words you shouldn't have removed `&&` from before `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make`. Your new snippet can be fixed by adding `&&` in the right place (`--enable-libvpx && \`).

This would be less confusing if the original code was of the following form:

```sh
… \
&& PATH=… PKG_CONFIG_PATH=… ./configure \
  … \
  --enable-nonfree \
&& PATH=… make \
&& …
```

Now if you removed the whole `--enable-nonfree \` line, then the necessary `&&` before `PATH=… make` would survive.

---

Side note: some backslashes in the original code are redundant because `&& \` at the very end of the line [can be just `&&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281310/108618). If you decide to place `&&` at the beginning of the next line instead, then `\` in the current line cannot be omitted.

Comment: Ahhh, I just cut out the &&. Well, stupid mistake. I didn't know the 'foo=bar baz' variable bash magic, thanks for the input!